# Sharepoint document shared with me no longer opens in browser

Tags: microsoft-word, onedrive, sharepoint

My colleague J at another institution shared a read-only Sharepoint document with me and other colleagues at other institutions via link sharing. I was able to view the whole document in my browser without issue. Now, when I attempt to access the file I can only see a one-page image of it. It does not even load Word so I cannot perform any actions with that image. The file still shows in my institutional OneDrive, but clicking on that link gives me the same image instead of the file.

I need to access the live document.

I don't know what caused me to lose access unless it was a result of downloading the file to my machine, but that seems like unexpected behaviour to me.

J has tried sharing the file directly with me, but that still takes me to the same image.

Another colleague S at the same institution as J has shared a different document with me via link sharing, and I can access that file without issue.

Our colleagues at the other institutions can still access J's document.

I have tried both Safari and Chrome, with the same result on both. I have tried logging in to my institutional account again. I have tried removing the file from my OneDrive but get an 'Access Denied' error; I have also tried loading a preview of the document but get a 'This item might not exist or is unavailable' message (however, the same two things happen with the other colleague S's document which I *can* access, so they may be a red herring).

I suspect that the issue may be with our respective institutions' security/permissions/authorisation but am stuck with what to try to troubleshoot this since I can access S's document and since others can access J's document.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to start by asking your respective IT departments regarding this. If it's policy, they're the ones who've set that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Safari, followed the link to the document and could open the document properly. Word loaded correctly in browser, including a 'log in' button. I logged in and had the original error again. I closed the tab and followed the link again, and could see the document while logged in.